# SSH won't find private key with -i parameter

Tags: ssh, private-key

My SSH connection works fine if I do this:

ssh myuser@myserver.com -i ~/.ssh/myserver

However if I omit the '-i', it demands a password and I have no idea why. It seems that my SSH client is not configured to check ~/.ssh.  I have set 700 permissions on the folder and the files but still nothing : /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to change or need to set the IdentityFile in your ssh config.

Edit or Insert the line, into the File /etc/ssh/ssh_conf:

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myserver
```

Normaly you only have one private key. If you have multiple private key's it's probably the best way to create "config" file in your ".ssh directory"

```
host myserver
 Hostname myserver
 user whatever
 port 22
 identityfile ~/.ssh/myserver
```

Now you can connect to your server by typping

```
ssh myserver
```

Comment: Do I need to do this for every identity file? Because that's not how my local computer works, it just finds it by magic.

Comment: normaly you only have one private key... you don't need to create for each server it's own private key :-)

Comment: Aahh! It's this misunderstanding that's causing the problem, all works now :) cheers. Didn't even need to write that in the config file, just name it id_dsa

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution, add something like this to your .ssh/config file:

```
host myserver
hostname myserver.com
identityfile ~/.ssh/myserver
user myuser
```

and you'll be fine with 'ssh myserver'.